# SQLite datatype size

Tags: sqlite, types, size

I modified the size of the datatype of SQLite database, like int(1), real(4), but the .db file size has not changed.I have a large amount of data, so I want to reduce the size of DB file as much as possible.

Comment: you might need to use `VACUUM`: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html excerpt: "Unless SQLite is running in 'auto_vacuum=FULL' mode, when a large amount of data is deleted from the database file it leaves behind empty space, or "free" database pages. This means the database file might be larger than strictly necessary. Running VACUUM to rebuild the database reclaims this space and reduces the size of the database file."

Answer (score 0):

> I modified the size of the datatype of SQLite database, like int(1), real(4), but the .db file size has not changed.

These changes/uses make no difference at all, due to:-

SQLite only having a limited number of types (type affinities) they are:-

- INTEGER
- TEXT
- REAL
- BLOB
- NUMERIC
- Any type specified will be considered as one of the above based upon a simple set of rules (e.g. int(1) will be considered as having a type affinity of INTEGER because it contains int (see 3.1. in the link below)).

And that, any type will be stored with a storage class that is one off:-

- NULL
- INTEGER
- REAL
- TEXT
- BLOB
- With the exception of the rowid and an alias of the rowid, which must be a an integer value, any type can be stored in any column type.

And then that the actual value will be stored nearly in as little space as it can be (down to a minimum of a byte). For an Integer value it will be stored as 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 or 8 bytes.

**See [Datatypes in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)**

> I have a large amount of data, so I want to reduce the size of DB file as much as possible.

You need to consider suitable use of **[VACUUM](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html)** and if using **[WAL mode](https://sqlite.org/wal.html)** suitable checkpointing.